GPU in Neural Net slow
I am trying to run the following code in Colab via GPU:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()  # Use this to upload your data files

def load_and_preprocess_data(city, start_year, end_year):
    train_file = f'{city}{start_year}.csv'
    test_file = f'{city}{end_year}.csv'

    train_data = pd.read_csv(train_file, header=None)
    test_data = pd.read_csv(test_file, header=None)

    x_train = train_data.iloc[1:, :].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0).values.astype(np.float32)
    y_test = test_data.iloc[0, :].apply(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else 0).values.astype(np.float32)

    return x_train, y_test


def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader, epochs):
    model.train()
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x_batch, y_batch in train_loader:
            x_batch, y_batch = x_batch.to('cuda'), y_batch.to('cuda')
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = model(x_batch)
            loss = criterion(outputs, y_batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

def evaluate_model(model, x_train_tensor, y_test_tensor):
    model.eval()
    with torch.no_grad():
        predictions = model(x_train_tensor.to('cuda'))
        mse = nn.MSELoss()(predictions, y_test_tensor.to('cuda')).item()
    return {'mse': mse}

class SimpleNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim1, hidden_dim2, dropout_rate):
        super(SimpleNN, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim1)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim1, hidden_dim2)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim2, 1)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_rate)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.dropout(x)
        x = self.sigmoid(self.fc3(x))
        return x

def grid_search(city, start_year, end_year, params):
    x_train, y_test = load_and_preprocess_data(city, start_year, end_year)
    input_dim = x_train.shape[0]

    x_train_tensor = torch.tensor(x_train).float().T
    y_test_tensor = torch.tensor(y_test).float().reshape(-1, 1)
    
    x_train_tensor = x_train_tensor.to('cuda')
    y_test_tensor = y_test_tensor.to('cuda')

    batch_size = 32
    train_dataset = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train_tensor, y_test_tensor)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    best_score = float('inf')
    best_params = None

    for params in ParameterGrid(param_grid):
        model = SimpleNN(input_dim, params['hidden_dim1'], params['hidden_dim2'], params['dropout_rate']).to('cuda')
        
        criterion = nn.BCELoss()
        optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=params['learning_rate'])

        train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, train_loader, params['epochs'])

        metrics = evaluate_model(model, x_train_tensor, y_test_tensor)
        if metrics['mse'] < best_score:
            best_score = metrics['mse']
            best_params = params

    return best_params, best_score

# Example usage
param_grid = {
    'hidden_dim1': [128, 64, 32],
    'hidden_dim2': [64, 32, 16],
    'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.06, 0.1],
    'dropout_rate': [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7],
    'epochs': [10, 30, 50, 70, 100]
}

cities = 'albany'
grid_search_year_pairs = [
    (2006, 2011)
]

for start_year, end_year in grid_search_year_pairs:
    best_params, best_score = grid_search(cities, start_year, end_year, param_grid)
    print(f"Best params: {best_params}, Best score: {best_score}")


Specifically, in the above I am trying to perform a grid search over param_grid. The process however is very slow and I am wondering if I have used the GPU correctly or if I am doing something else wrong.
I really cannot see any reason for this code to be slow rather than searching among all the combinations of parameters in the grid. Do you think it's normal or am I doing some mistake here?

Grid search takes a long time, god knows what you mean with "slow".

Slow in this case means more than 15 minutes per city. The cities are 150
